# How does a static site works?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, next.js

I'm trying to get my head over this new static site generator paradigm. How does it work exactly?

Let's say I have a blog and I used Nextjs or Gatsby to generate the static pages:

- Does it create a new page for every blog post?
- As I publish new posts, do I need to build it all over again? If so, is there some kind of routine that does this from time to time?

Comment: Probably a bit too broad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer this for Gatsby. I'm sure the are folks on here who know a lot more about Gatsby than I do, but here goes.

- "Does it create a new page for every blog post?"

Gatsby will statically render anything that it can. This means some statically rendered HTML, like a collection of blog posts, and React components. From the Gatsby homepage:

> Gatsby.js is a static PWA (Progressive Web App) generator. You get code and data splitting out-of-the-box. Gatsby loads only the critical HTML, CSS, data, and JavaScript so your site loads as fast as possible. Once loaded, Gatsby prefetches resources for other pages so clicking around the site feels incredibly fast.

- "As I publish new posts, do I need to build it all over again? If so, is there some kind of routine that does this from time to time?"

A build step, such as `gatsby build`, would be part of any standard deploy process. In development these static pages are rebuilt on save via hot reloading.